# Changing a composable based on state

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a list item that can have an image at the start of the view, and when edit mode is selected, a switch replaces the image and it becomes draggable. My initial thought was to use a data class for the image, since the developer would need to pass both the `Painter` object as well as a `contentDescription` for accessibility reasons, like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ListItem(
   startIcon: StartIcon? = null,
   title: String
) {
   Row(...) {
      startIcon?.let {
         Image(painter = startIcon.painter, contentDescription = startIcon.description)
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

After reading comments on reddit about a medium article on the topic ([see here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/o384hy/avoid_pain_in_jetpack_compose/h2d172m/?context=3)) , most of the commenters seem to agree that using data classes for this purpose will create performance issues due to recomposition initialising new data classes willy nilly, and recommended using state instead.

How would i go about creating state for these two cases? It seems obvious that an edit mode would be a state, but I'm not sure if it overcomplicated for whether or not an image should be shown. Additionally, how would this look? What is the best way to manage this state while ensuring the view itself is stateless? I'm pretty new to Compose, and given how important it is i'd like to ensure i do not start out learning bad habits and antipatterns

Thanks!